# Security: Handle Multiple User Rights

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, rights

Now that my project is almost finished I am trying to implement the login and security.
I got a table in my database with all the users in it.
Next to the normal login and password columns I also got 7 booleans.
Those booleans represent the categories(folders) which the users may access or not.

After the user logins I put the record (user) in my session.
So depending on those booleans I will display tabs in my masterpage.

But how do I implent the security measures which redirects the user back to the login when they aren't logged in yet or when they don't got the proper rights to be on that page.

Somebody told me to add some code in de global.asax but I have no experience with it. And got no idea on how to start and it seems like i can't find any examples on the internet

Comment: Your method is not scalable - as usual the answer is to normalise your data properly. 

Note that your access model is fairly crude too - and does not account for the usual [CRUD][1] authorizations model.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Membership sounds like what you need. No point writing something from scratch when your chosen Framework will already handle it for you, right?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Comment: @Beejee, The ASP.Net role provider will handle your security flags much more cleanly then having 7 booleans too.

Comment: When you want to use this can you make your own login and create page? Because i use my own controls (buttons and textfields) which fit the template and style of the website and company

Comment: Yes, definitely (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) - uss CSS to apply your house styles.

Comment: But i already made custom controls for all the other pages so i would like to use those

Comment: You may still be able to - I suggest you have a play with Membership, Login etc. first and then once you're more familiar with the inner workings, perhaps derive your custom controls from a Login control?

Comment: One last comment:
I looked arround for some tutorials about it but they were never using somthing that corresponds with my booleans. 
The administrator is the one who gives the other user rights to go to the page but in all the expamples they make use one role.
I can't make a role for each combination of the 7 booleans thats just nuts.

Comment: You wouldn't make a role for each _combination_ of the Booleans - just 7 roles, of which each User could belong to one or more.